# Format Sitemap Style Memaid JS

Tags: javascript, sitemap, mermaid

I am using the following [Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/) MD to create a sitemap.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js">
      </script>
    <script>mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <div class="mermaid">
      flowchart TD
        A(Home)-->B(Col 1 - Level 1)
        A-->C(Col 2 - Level 1)
        C-->F(Col 2 - Level 2)
        A-->G(Col 3 - Level 1)
        G-->H(Col 3 - Level 2)
        H-->I(Col 3 - Level 3)
        A-->J(Col 4 - Level 1)
        J-->K(Col 4 - Level 2)
        A-->L(Col 5 - Level 1)
        B-->E(End)
        F-->E
        I-->E
        K-->E
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which renders like the image below. See the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/whoacowboy/pen/yLzwezo).

[image]

I would like it to respect the column order and align it more like an old school sitemap.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the built-in [subgraph](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=subgraphs) functionality. The following appears to do what you want:

```
      flowchart TD
      subgraph one
        A(Home)-->B(Col 1 - Level 1)
        A-->C(Col 2 - Level 1)
        A-->G(Col 3 - Level 1)
        A-->J(Col 4 - Level 1)
        A-->L(Col 5 - Level 1)
      end
      subgraph two
        C-->F(Col 2 - Level 2)
        J-->K(Col 4 - Level 2)
        G-->H(Col 3 - Level 2)
      end
        H-->I(Col 3 - Level 3)
        B-->E(End)
        F-->E
        I-->E
        K-->E
```

Comment: It would be cool to format it with straighter lines, but I'll take it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @whoacowboy you can specify a [line curve style](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html#styling-line-curves) in the initialisation config, [like in this example](https://codepen.io/wayneparkes/pen/WNaMrpK).
`stepAfter` or `stepBefore` will help you accomplish your goal.